# Is text-underline a property?

Tags: html, css, text, properties

I got a stylesheet which has a `text-underline:none`  property, is it really a CSS property?

Comment: No, it isn't. The one the person wanted to use is `text-decoration: none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't a valid CSS property. Instead, you can use `text-decoration: none`.

The `text-underline` property is often found in CSS generated by Microsoft Word.

Comment: When it is not a property then why Microsoft Word use it ? Is there any browser which support this property?

Comment: I don't know of any browsers that support it. It might just be used for MS Word (e.g., when importing).